# IOS - Image not displaying programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an image set in code but the image does not display. When I run this on the iPhone or simulator the image does not show.

I will provide you with the code.

Here is the code so far:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:70.0f/255.0f
                                                green:111.0f/255.0f
                                                 blue:162.0f/255.0f
                                                alpha:1.0f];

    UIView *viewTopBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:viewTopBar];
    viewTopBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:53.0f/255.0f
                                       green:85.0f/255.0f
                                        blue:127.0f/255.0f
                                       alpha:1.0f];
    viewTopBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,25,320,40);

    UIWebView *viewMusic = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:viewMusic];
    viewMusic.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    viewMusic.frame = CGRectMake(0,65,320,270);
    viewMusic.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=NO;
    viewMusic.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;

    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* path = [bundle  pathForResource: @"index" ofType: @"html"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [viewMusic loadRequest: req];

    UIImageView *imageFBButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginfb.gif"]];
    imageFBButton.frame = CGRectMake(43, 421, 234, 49);
    [self.view addSubview:imageFBButton];
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you actually have an image with the name "loginfb.gif" in your resource bundle?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at `imageFBButton.frame = CGRectMake(43, 421, 234, 49);` then hover over `imageFBButton` and click the eye icon. Do you see an image there?

Comment: the image is in the app folder

Comment: @remus it says could not load data for imageFBButton

Comment: There ya go - it's either a bad resource or missing. Double check that it's added to your target?

Comment: @remus its in the copy bundle resources

Comment: @remus i created the image using adobe photoshop

Comment: @remus then dragged the image from folder to Xcode

Comment: Worked! i didn't save the file properly when using photoshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code. It loaded the image without any issue. I believe its a bad resource or missing as "remus" said. Attached the screen shot. you can see the google image on the specified location.

[image]